# Log net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer getType

Tags: java, xmlserializer

I'm using net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer
And I have this error

```
25 déc. 2012 18:20:38 net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer getType
INFO: Using default type string
```

And I want to disable it.
Is there a method to disable error log for this library ?

Thanks

Comment: this is not an error it is info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch off the logs(log4j) from a class like this.

```
log4j.logger.net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer=OFF
```

Comment: I'm using org.commons.logging and I've found this solution `static {
  System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log","org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
 }`

Comment: Its always better to switch off the logs in a configuration file rather than wring a code to do it. NoOpLog can be used but it needs u to add code,and also just check if it is switching off all the logs 4 all the classes or just for the class which has the static block.

Comment: With configuration file you mean something like your code `log4j.logger.net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer=OFF` ? Because i'm not using log4J

Comment: you said that your are using comons-logging rite ? just go through this page for the configuration part of log4j http://commons.apache.org/logging/guide.html#Configuring Log4J